# android standard oauth authentication and add facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, oauth

I have a simple app with oauth mechanism of login to service with such things like: login, password, access token, refresh token, etc. Right now I would like to add Facebook and Google login option. 
I wonder how should I handle this operation. For example when I choose Facebook login and everything goes well I retrieve LoginResult (object from fb sdk) with AccessToken. 
So what should I do?

1. Should I pass this token to backend in order to authenticate a user?
2. Or maybe get user id from facebook and pass it to backend as well?
3. Should I execute some operation on server side?

I won't use third party library for this thing, because on server side I already have an implementation of oauth mechanism.